# Show alert if user come to my website with uc browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a website in which I want to pop alert for those visitors who are using UC browser. (Below code is in javascript). **I want the answer also in javascript**.

For UC Browser

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCBrowser/') >= 0) {
       alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
</script>
```

For UC mini

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/^Mozilla\/5\.0 .+ Gecko\/$/)) {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
</script>
```

I know one of them will work. I found this code from the internet. please guide me if this code correct or not. And most important **I want to show alert once per day for the same user with Ip address**. Please help me with this.

Comment: You say `I want` a lot, but you haven't shown us what you have tried yourself to create this.

Comment: Because I don't know nothing that's why I ask question

Comment: You should be aware of that it's required that you try yourself to create this, if not then SO would turn into 1 big coding service.

Answer (score 1):

for **UCBrowser**

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCBrowser/') >= 0
```

mean that in the userAgent you have "UCBrowser/" string

for **UCMini** you can do this:

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCMini/') >= 0
```

If you want to join the two conditions do as following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCBrowser/') >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCMini/') >= 0) {
       alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
```

---

### Complete solution

Now to do display the message only one time a day you need to store the last alert timestamp, you can choose your favorite method, I think that the most simple is using the local storage, here the complete code with comment:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCBrowser/') >= 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' UCMini/') >= 0) {

  // get current timestamp
  now = new Date().getTime();

  // get last timestamp or zero if not present
  last = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last') || 0 )

  // set the last timestamp for next visit
  localStorage.setItem('last', now);

  // if fist time visit (last == 0) or more the 24 hours (86400 seconds) -> alert
  if ( last == 0 ){
    alert("Alert first time");
  }else if( last != 0 && now - last > 86400 ){
    alert("Alert next time");
  }

}
```

Comment: I check this on google chrome and opera for changing if condition that work fine but i don;t have UC browser right now but when i test on it I'll definitely told you and Thanks